# WooCommerce shipping - Different product different shipping?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm on WooCommerce Version 2.6.4 and trying to figure out how to set shipping to individual project.

We have products come with different weights and sizes. So we want to have different different shipping cost applied to each of them.

For instance: **Product A costs £10 and its shipping is £5.**

So if you buy **2** of product A, then:

```
2 X £10 = £20 (cost of 2 items)
2 X £5 = £10 (shipping)
```

If I use the flat rate just as in the [guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/flat-rate-shipping/)

```
5 * [qty]
```

Then this apply to all products.

But I have other products, eg **Product B, costs £20, shipping costs £7**. Then how can I do that with that flat rate above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create shipping classes for each of your product variations which require one. On your product page, add the attributes for the product, then add the variations, based on the added attributes. Once loaded, you may select the individual product variations to modify price, size, weight, inventory, and shipping class for each specific product variation.

**To Setup product variations:**

Add a new product.

Set product to Variable Product.

Select Attribute Tab.

Add Attribute Name (in this case I choose "Size") & add Attribute Values (separate values with a pipe) & select "Use for Variation". Save Attributes:
[image: Add Attributes]

Select Variations Tab & Select "Add Variation" or "Create Variations from All Attributes":
[image: Add Variation]

Select the variation you'd like to modify the shipping for and adjust shipping.
[image: Add Shipping]

Comment: Thanks but it's so abstract. Any concrete examples out there?

Comment: I don't have variations for my products.

Comment: @teelou I added a few step instructions for you to follow. If you are still having difficulty, search the web using your favorite search engine for "WooCommerce Add Variation" and you'll get videos and other tutorials from a multitude of folks, including the WooCommerce dev & training team. Hope this is helpful.